# 3D mousemove effect on image gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to replicate the effect of the image gallery like this site
http://claiming-needles.net/

maybe someone can help me, I tried various solutions, one of these are written below in jquery.

```
$(".gallery").on('mousemove', function(e){
   centerX = $(this).width();
   let moveX = centerX - e.offsetX;
   $(this).css({'transform':'perspective(500px) rotateY('+ moveX/100+ 'deg)'})
})
```

Comment: Should `centerX` be set to `Math.floor($(this).width() / 2)`? that would represent the center of the image. Also, why are you dividing `moveX` by `100`? You are likely rotating by a very small number of degrees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Oliver Dunk says, it is hard to tell what wrong without the DOM. I think there lays the solution. It looks like the effect works only when the perspective property is on the mother of our element. This looks to work:

```js
$("img").on('mousemove', function(e){
   centerX = $(this).width();
   centerY = $(this).height();
   
   moveX = centerX - e.offsetX;
   moveY = centerY - e.offsetY;
   
   $("#output").text(moveX)
   $(this).css({'transform':'rotateY('+ moveX/100+ 'deg) rotateX('+ moveY/10+ 'deg)'})
   
})
```

```css
div { perspective: 100px; padding: 100px;}

img {border: 1px solid orange}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I did when investigating this was to remove the jQuery. Feel free to change it back, but at least for me, I'm more familiar with the native browser APIs.

Here's the code I ended up with:

```
document.querySelector(".gallery").onmousemove = function(e) {
   centerX = e.target.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2;
   let moveX = centerX - e.offsetX;
   e.target.style.transform = `rotateY(${moveX / 4}deg) perspective(500px)`;
};
```

It's hard to tell for certain what's wrong without the full DOM you're working with. When playing, however, I did notice two things that might explain your trouble:

- The `onmousemove` event isn't called when you are outside of the transformed element. This means the area where moving your mouse has an effect reduces over time.
- You're not dividing the central coordinates by two. This means you're getting the offset from the right side.
- Unless this element is huge, 100 is much too large of a scale factor.

At the very least, I think you should be thinking of some sort of container element to track the mouse and its offset.

I hope all of this helps. Let me know if you figure it out!